# Exportar Dados mysql para txt

Tags: php

Boa Tarde Galera,
sou novo em php, tenho uma tabela no mysql e estou acessando via phpmyadmin, preciso pegar dados de uma tabela e jogar em um txt separado por virgulas, é algo simples, mas não estou achando na internet. Alguém poderia me indicar um site ou um tutorial que vocês sabem que possa me atender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Selecione o banco de dados > Exportar > CSV > Executar